# Javascript gives `invalidcharactererror`

Tags: javascript

The last line of Javascript code below gives me an `InvalidCharacterError`, I can't figure out why:

```
var iCounter=0;
var calendarText = document.createElement("input");
calendarText.setAttribute("SetAttribute(" + iCounter + ")", "onkeyup");
```

Can anyone tell why?

Comment: DO NOT ADD EVENTS WITH SETATTRIBUTE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 3):

Attribute names cannot contain `(` or `)`. You could change it to

```
calendarText.setAttribute("SetAttribute_" + iCounter, "onkeyup");
```

If you use custom attributes, consider using [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

If you just passed the arguments in the wrong order, I can only recommend to **always** [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) first:

> `element.setAttribute(name, value);`

But in that case, you should [learn about the better ways to attach event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). E.g. a slightly better way would be

```
calendarText.onkeyup = function() {
    SetAttribute(i);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
var iCounter=0;
var calendarText = document.createElement("input");
calendarText.setAttribute("onkeyup", "SetAttribute(" + iCounter + ")");
```

The second parameter of setAttribute method is the value of the property (which is the first one)

```
elementNode.setAttribute(name,value)
```

Comment: Good catch with the argument order!